# Applications Using Machine Learning Without Cloud

Tags: machine-learning, tic-tac-toe, machine-learning-model

I have seen various methods of deploying machine learning models on the cloud, but I just wanted to know if we can create a program that uses machine learning not from the cloud but instead uses the model trained on the same computer. What I mean is can I create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game where the computer uses machine learning to play against the human player, with both the game file and the model residing on the same computer, one communicating with the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep!  You can.  It’s called reinforcement learning.  There are some pretty good tutorials about it here:

https://github.com/simoninithomas/Deep_reinforcement_learning_Course